# Magento 2 products disappear on category pages after importing new products

Tags: magento, magento2, reindex, magento2.2

I have a Magento 2.2.2 store with 15900 products. Lately, I imported about 300 new products and I understand all products are disappeared in category pages. after some tests, I understand that when I delete new imported products, all products are available again in category pages. 
 
Also when I imported products again, I understand that products are available in category pages during my manual reindex. but when it's over, products are disappeared again. 
 
I almost tried everything on google and I couldn't find the solution. 
I tried to reindex, reset reindex, clear cache, deploy, increase and decrease bachSize file and ...

Answer (score 0):

steps to debug:

1. Try to export some products and comparing with your importing list and check if anything missing in your importing list.
2. Try to access www.example.com/catalog/product/view/id/your-product-id in frontend if you can open that product page. If successful, you need to do a url reindex. Try to execute a simple standard export and then re-import: for example, re-import only sku and url_key attributes, and Magento should reindex the rewrites.

Hope it helps